# Qt точка входа в процедуру не найдена в библиотеке dll

Tags: qt

При открытии `exe` файла выдает ошибку. Все длл добавил, не знаю, в чем проблема.

В *Qt* собираю файл релиза.
Далее добавляю все необходимые длл.
После этого появляется такая ошибка при запуске `ехе` файла программы:

`Точка входа в процедуру ?focusOutEvent@Qlabel@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z
 Не найдена в библиотеке DLL`

Далее идёт путь к `ехе` файлу.

Comment: Убери скриншот и добавь подробное описание того, что делаешь.

Comment: Ошибка "точка входа не найдена" говорит о том, что в папке лежит не та dll. Самая распространенная ошибка - положить библиотеки из папки с креатором вместо собственно Qt